# About $ A(f(x),g(x)) = h(x) = 1 + \int_0^x f(x - t) g(t) dt $

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, integral-transforms

Consider the transforms

$$ A(f(x),g(x)) = h(x) = 1 + \int_0^x f(x - t) g(t) dt $$

$$ B(h(x),g(x)) = f(x) $$

$$ C(h(x),f(x)) = g(x) $$

Where the functions on the LHS are given.

Notice $B,C$ are the inverses of $A$.

How to compute $B,C$ ??
Is there an integral representation for $B$ or $C$ ?

How to find

$$ f(x) = h(x) $$

For a given $g(x) $ ?

How to find

$$ g(x) = h(x) $$

For a given $f(x) $ ?

It reminds me of Laplace transforms and convolution ... not sure If that helps.